# how to fix the plupload issue whereby it is not accepting big dimension .gif files?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, plupload

the problem is ,when I try to upload big dimensioned .gif files, it doesn't get accepted,
but lower ones are ok. while other photo extensions such as jpg, jpeg are ok. any work arounds for this ?
here's the options that I have in the plupload

```
            'options' => array(
                'runtimes' => 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
                'url' => $this->createUrl('upload'),
                "max_file_size" => '10mb',
                'chunk_size' => '1mb',
                'unique_names' => true,
                'resize' => array('width' => 900, 'height' => 900, 'quality' => 90),
                'filters' => array(
                    array("title" => "Image files", "extensions" => "jpg,gif,png,jpeg")
                ),
```

Comment: check your max upload size setting ini your `php.ini` file

Comment: the max_file_uploads = 20; ,the gif file that I was trying to upload was 1.8mb only, but the dimension is 4000 x 2300 ,any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: what about `upload_max_filesize` did you check that too?

Comment: the upload_max_filesize = 2M ..but as I said , the gif file that I was trying to upload is only 1.46MB

Comment: It doesn't matter. The server could be taking up more when uploading. Increase it to 10 or 20m see if that works.

Comment: it didn't helped at all...have you worked before with plupload or not ?

Comment: No I haven't just general PHP uploading. In regular PHP some set the upload file max in their form, so if you have that also, could be it.

Comment: in you notice the code that i pasted, the max_file_size is set to 10mb already

Comment: I don't know what else it could be then.

Answer (score 2):

Plupload can only resize png and jpeg files ( [see for example the gears runtime source](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/1.x/src/javascript/plupload.gears.js#L270))

I guess your problem is with chunking handling.

Your jpgs and png are resized on the client side and get under the 1Mb chunk size, while your gifs do not.
You should try disabling chunking and see if it makes a difference. If so, you should have a look at your chunking handling or request size limit on the server side, and fix it